# Is it possible to filter on column1 = "value1" OR column2 = "value2", showing the union of the two filters?

Tags: quality-center

I have a requirement where in i have to filter the records and get the union of two columns in QC API. Need help if someone has tried and was successful.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here - do you need to retrieve records from the *same* data source where column1 = value1 or column2 = value2, or are the columns from two different data sources? The first case is a simple query, the second is a union.